# Gradle doesn't catch exception

Tags: gradle

I am running a very simple Gradle  task.
which run Yarn command - yarn_test which run Selenium tests.
I am using com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0 plugin in order to run Yarn commands
my task look like -

```
task run_tests(type: YarnTask) {
try {
    args = ['test']
}catch (all){
    println('Tests failed!')
}}
```

and in my packge.json i have:
"test": "mocha --timeout 25000 ./automation/test --reporter xunit-file"

even when I changed it to run as exec 
        `executable "sh"`
        `args "-c", "yarn test"`

I got the same error, so it is not something with the plugin but, with Gradle try-catch

when even one test fail no meter why I want to catch the exception.
but for some reason it doesn't get caught.

when I run with --stacktrace this is what I get-

> error Command failed with exit code 2.
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
>
> Task :run_tests FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':run_tests'.
>   Process 'command '/DATA/build/workspace/build_build/.gradle/yarn/yarn-v1.3.2/bin/yarn'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   * Try:
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   * Exception is:
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':run_tests'.

What am I missing?
All I want is to print some error, and finish the build.. but not with exception?!
Gradle 4.7, run on Ubuntu with Gradle wrapper.
Thanks

**EDIT**

even when i run just

```
sh: exit 1
```

I got same result so, it has to be something with gradle try-catch and not with yarn ormocha etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `try`/`catch` is covering the **configuration** gradle build phase, not the **execution** phase. The full gradle build lifecycle is covered [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html), but I'll include the basic descriptions of each phase at the end of this answer.

It [looks like](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/moowork/gradle/node/yarn/YarnTask.groovy#L64) `YarnTask` supports the `ignoreExitValue` property, so you should at least be able to do something like:

```
task run_tests(type: YarnTask) {
    args = ['test']
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
```

to just ignore the result; I think you can make it even a bit more sophisticated, like:

```
task run_tests(type: YarnTask) {
    args = ['test']
    ignoreExitValue = true
    doLast {
        if(result.getExitValue() != 0){
            println "Tests failed!"
        }
    }
}
```

The `doLast` action will be executed after completion of all of the task's defined actions (e.g., after the tests have been run).

---

Phases of the [Gradle Build Lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html), the very short version:

1. **Initialization** - Determine which projects/subprojects will be built
2. **Configuration** - Configures all the projects/tasks (executes the build scripts, which prepares the tasks)
3. **Execution** - Executes the tasks themselves

Comment: almost perfect-     Could not get unknown property 'execResult' for task ':run_tests' of type com.moowork.gradle.node.yarn.YarnTask. maybe i should open issue in github?

Comment: Looking at the plugin source again, can you try with using just `result` instead of `execResult`?