# Unable to catch exception of Gradle task of type Exec

Tags: android, gradle, try-catch

I've created a gradle task to check if a program is installed, it works fine but I discovered that it can throw an exception on environments where the command I am executing does not exist. I've tried to catch the exception that is thrown but no luck. How can I gracefully handle the exception and continue the build process if my task fails due to the command not existing?

**Error:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':isGitLFSInstalled'.

  > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'command''

**Code:**

```
task isGitLFSInstalled(type: Exec) {
commandLine 'command', '-v', 'git-lfs' // Fails here on environments that dont have "command"
ignoreExitValue true
standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

ext.output = {
    return standardOutput.toString()
}

doLast {
    if (execResult.exitValue != 0) {
        throw new GradleException("Git LFS is not installed, please build project after installing Git LFS.\n" +
                "Refer to the following URL to setup Git LFS: https://git-lfs.github.com/")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're facing is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51735570/5288316). Surrounding `commandLine` with try/catch doesn't work for a simple reason: `commandLine` doesn't execute your command, it just sets the command to be executed by the Exec task when it will be run.

One way would be not to use tasks to execute the command. For example, you could use ProcessBuilder wrapped in try/catch in `finalizedBy`, which will only be run during the execution phase:

```
task myTask {
    finalizedBy {
        try {
            def proc = new ProcessBuilder("command", "-v", "git-lfs")
            proc.start().waitFor()
            // Do something with stdout or whatever.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            println("Couldn't find git-lfs.")
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have much time right now, but I hope that helps.

Comment: Actually you can get rid of the function, `finalizedBy` block is only called during execution phase.